# .NET/C# equivalent to Java Metadata Interface (JMI)

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any open source project/APIs for .NET/C# equivalent to Java Metadata Interface (JMI)?

http://java.sun.com/products/jmi/

Answer (score 1):

I sure hope not. It looks awfully like [architecture astronautics](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000018.html) to me. A Java binding for a metamodel for defining models? That's about 3 removes from actual source code, by my count.

However, from further browsing [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=175938), it looks like the **practical upshot** is like what .NET calls the [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx). You could start there.

Comment: Wrong MOF, as I understand it. See my comments on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Barry that JMI looks like architecture astronautics, and I don't know of any similar initiative on the .NET field. Fortunately.

However, I don't think that the CodeDOM is comparable to JMI. CodeDOM is about generating and managing *code* programmatically, whereas JMI is about generating and managing *metadata*. According to the JMI FAQs and associated documentation, JMI aims to be expressive in the areas of computer programming but also databases, conceptual models, communication protocols, configuration management, data sources, etc.